# Expand roots into a polynomial

Tags: code-golf, polynomials

### Challenge

Given the roots of a polynomial separated by spaces as input, output the expanded form of the polynomial.

For example, the input

```
1 2
```

represents this equation:

```
(x-1)(x-2)
```

And should output:

```
x^2-3x+2
```

The exact format of output is not important, it can be:

```
1x^2+-3x^1+2x^0
```

or:

```
0 0 0
1x^3+0x^2+0x^1+0
```

or:

```
3 14 15 92
1x^4+-124x^3+3241x^2+-27954x^1+57960
```

### Scoring/Rules

- `eval` and likes are disallowed.
- You may use any version of Python *or any other language*.

Comment: What about built-ins like `numpy.poly`?

Comment: @Dennis numpy is not built-in i think!

Comment: Python + NumPy answers are generally accepted, but that's beside the point. Can I use a function that turns roots into polynomial coefficients? I'm asking since you banned eval, and that's considerably more powerful than eval.

Comment: @Dennis That pretty much the whole think! But go ahead! Since the same function is built-in in most languages.

Comment: can we assume the roots are integers? can we assume they are nonnegative integers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Jelly, 15 bytes

```
Æṛ‘Ė’Uj€“x^”j”+
```

This uses `Æṛ` to construct the coefficients of a monic polynomial with given roots. [Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=w4bhuZvigJjEluKAmVVq4oKs4oCceF7igJ1q4oCdKw&input=&args=MywgMTQsIDE1LCA5Mg)

#### How it works

```
Æṛ‘Ė’Uj€“x^”j”+  Main link. Argument: A (list of roots)

Æṛ               Yield the coefficients of a monic polynomial with roots A.
  ‘              Increment each root by 1.
   Ė             Enumerate the roots, yielding
                 [[1, coeff. of x^0 + 1], ... [n + 1, coeff. of x^n + 1]].
    ’            Decrement all involved integers, yielding
                 [[0, coeff. of x^0], ... [n, coeff. of x^n]].
     U           Upend to yield [[coeff. of x^0, 0], ... [coeff. of x^n, n]].
      j€“x^”     Join each pair, separating by 'x^'.
            j”+  Join the pairs, separating by '+'.
```

### Alternate version, 24 bytes

```
1WW;ð0;_×µ/‘Ė’Uj€“x^”j”+
```

This uses no polynomial-related built-ins. [Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=MVdXO8OwMDtfw5fCtS_igJjEluKAmVVq4oKs4oCceF7igJ1q4oCdKw&input=&args=MywgMTQsIDE1LCA5Mg)

#### How it works

```
1WW;ð0;_×µ/‘Ė’Uj€“x^”j”+  Main link. Argument: A (list of roots)

1WW                       Yield [[1]].
   ;                      Concatenate with A.
    ð    µ/               Reduce [[1]] + A by the following, dyadic chain:
     0;                     Prepend a zero to the left argument (initially [1]).
                            This multiplies the left argument by "x".
        ×                   Take the product of both, unaltered arguments.
                            This multiplies the left argument by "r", where r is
                            the root specified in the right argument.
      _                     Subtract.
                            This computes the left argument multiplied by "x-r".
           ‘Ė’Uj€“x^”j”+  As before.
```

Answer (score 4):

## [MATL](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MATL), 29 bytes

```
ljU"1@_hX+]tn:Pqv'+%gx^%g'wYD
```

Input is an array with the roots.

*EDITS:*

- *(May 20, 2016): the `X+` function has been removed, as `Y+` includes its functionality. So in the above code replace `X+` by `Y+`.*
- *(September 29, 2017): due to changes in the `YD` function, `w` in the above code should be removed.*

*The following link includes those changes.*

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/PycrVMnQIT4jUju2JM8qoLBMXVs1vSJONV090uX/f2MFQxMFQ1MFSyMA)

#### Explanation

This applies repeated convolution with terms of the form `[1, -r]` where `r` is a root.

```
l          % push number 1
jU         % take input string. Convert to number array
"          % for each root r
  1        %   push number 1
  @_       %   push -r
  h        %   concatenate horizontally
  X+       %   convolve. This gradually builds array of coefficients
]          % end for each
tn:Pq      % produce array [n-1,n-2,...,0], where n is the number of roots
v          % concatenate vertically with array of coefficients
'+%gx^%g'  % format string, sprintf-style
w          % swap
YD         % sprintf. Implicitly display
```

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby, 155 bytes

Anonymous function, input is an array of the roots.

Prints from lowest power first, so calling `f[[1,2]]` (assuming you assigned the function to `f`) returns the string `"2x^0+-3x^1+1x^2"`.

```
->x{j=-1
x.map{|r|[-r,1]}.reduce{|a,b|q=a.map{|c|b=[0]+b
b.map{|e|e*c}[1..-1]}
q.pop.zip(*q).map{|e|(e-[p]).reduce(:+)}}.map{|e|"#{e}x^#{j+=1}"}.join('+')}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Python 3, 453 bytes (Spaces removed and more) -> 392 bytes

```
import functools
import operator
print([('+'.join(["x^"+str(len(R))]+[str(q)+"x^"+str(r)if r>0else"{0:g}".format(q)for r,q in enumerate([sum(functools.reduce(operator.mul,(-int(R[n])for n,m in enumerate(j)if int(m)==1),1)for j in[(len(R)-len(bin(i)[2:]))*'0'+bin(i)[2:]for i in range(1,2**len(R))]if sum(1-int(k) for k in j)==p)for p in range(len(R))]) ][::-1]))for R in[input().split()]][0])
```

Check [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/595409/1683017), Will help understand the reason behind those two imports.

Comment: You could get rid of a lot of extra whitespace

Comment: @proudhaskeller You're right! I changed the rules kinda forgot to change my own answer.

Comment: `from operator import*`, `from functools import*` save a few bytes

Comment: `import functools,operator`

Answer (score 0):

## Haskell, 99

```
l%r=zipWith(-)(0:l)$map(r*)l++[0]
f e='0':do(c,i)<-zip(foldl(%)[1]e)[0..];'+':show c++"x^"++show i
```

prints the lower powers first, with an additional `0+` at the start. for example:

```
>f [1,1]
"0+1x^0+-2x^1+1x^2"
```

The function computes the coefficients by progressively adding more roots, like convolutions, but without the builtin.

Then we use the list monad to implicitly `concat` all of the different monomials.

Answer (score 0):

### Sage, 38 bytes

```py
lambda N:prod(x-t for t in N).expand()
```

[Try it online](http://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxLs81JzE1KSVTwsyooyk_RqNAtUUjLL1IoUcjMU_DT1EutKEjMS9HQ5OXi5SooyswDympEG-oYxWoi8Q10gBBFxFjH0ETH0FTHEqgQAOOyHB8=&lang=sage)

This defines an unnamed lambda that takes an iterable of roots as input and computes the product `(x-x_n) for x_n in roots`, then expands it.

Answer (score 0):

## Mathematica, 26 bytes

```
Expand@Product[x-k,{k,#}]&
```

Mathematica has powerful polynomial builtins.

### Usage

```
  f = Expand@Product[x-k,{k,#}]&
  f@{3, 14, 15, 92}
x^4 - 124 x^3 + 3241 x^2 - 27954 x + 57960
```

Answer (score 0):

### JavaScript (ES6), 96 bytes

```
a=>a.map(x=>r.map((n,i)=>(r[i]-=x*a,a=n),++j,r.push(a=0)),r=[j=1])&&r.map(n=>n+`x^`+--j).join`+`
```